# Can iPhone App access the Notes field in the Contact Book (assuming user allows access to contacts)

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

Can an iPhone App access the notes field in the Contact Book?   I am assuming that the user has permitted the app to allow access to "Contacts" when prompted.

Can all available fields in Contacts be accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you get the note value like you would for the other properties. For example, you can use `ABRecordCopyValue` with the `kABPersonNoteProperty`. See the [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html), notably the *Direct Interaction: Programmatically Accessing the Database* chapter.

For example, to get the last name, you would:

```
NSString *name = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
```

To get the note, you would:

```
NSString *note = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonNoteProperty));
```

See the *Constants* section of the [ABPerson Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW3) for a list of the properties that can be retrieved.